# Vs Code is marking codes as errors that aren't errors in Laravel. How can I stop it from showing those errors/any errors?

Tags: php, error-handling, visual-studio-code, laravel-8

Showing error while I was trying to add toastr

```
    <script>
        @if(Session::has('message'))

            var type = "{{ Session::get('alert-type','info') }}"

            switch(type){
            case 'info':
                toastr.info(" {{ Session::get('message') }} ");
            break;

            case 'success':
                toastr.success(" {{ Session::get('message') }} ");
            break;

            case 'warning':
                toastr.warning(" {{ Session::get('message') }} ");
            break;

            case 'error':
                toastr.error(" {{ Session::get('message') }} ");
            break;
            }
        @endif
    </script>
```

Here showing error under asset

```
<div class="flex-shrink-0 mr-20">
   <div class="bg-img h-50 w-50" style="background-image: url({{asset('backend/images/gallery/creative/img-1.jpg') }})"></div>
 </div>
```

I'm sure that those codes don't have any errors but the Vs Code keeps showing errors. Could it happen because of extensions?

[image: Bogas errors]

[image: Bogas errors 2]

Comment: Do you have a "blade" extension installed? That might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem resolves after Installing some blade, js extensions.